# What about this causes the syntax error? ('near &&')

Tags: bash, git-bash

A set of commands stringed together with "&&" doesn't work when aliased, works when entered directly.

I have a set of eleven commands for initializing Git, creating a new repo, creating some config files, and creating several branches.

I've combined these into single command stringed by &&s for convenience. This command works when pasted directly. It fails when I run an aliased version.

I've edited my `~/.bashrc` file to the following code:

```sh
alias repo='git init && hub create && echo "/node_modules" >.gitignore && tsc --init && git add -A && git commit -S -m "First commit" && git push -u origin master && git checkout -b dev && git push origin head && git checkout -b new_feature && git push origin head'
```

I've tried moving it to its own function:

```sh
createRepo () {
  git init 
  && hub create 
  && echo "/node_modules" >.gitignore 
  && tsc --init 
  && git add -A 
  && git commit -S -m "First commit"  
  && git push -u origin master  
  && git checkout -b dev 
  && git push origin head 
  && git checkout -b new_feature 
  && git push origin head
}

alias repo="createRepo"
```

And it gives the exact same result.

To be clear, pasting `git init && hub create && echo "/node_modules" >.gitignore && tsc --init && git add -A && git commit -S -m "First commit" && git push -u origin master && git checkout -b dev && git push origin head && git checkout -b new_feature && git push origin head` directly causes it to work as functioned.

It's only when I attempt to alias it that I get the syntax error.

I'm using nano

I expect `repo` in Bash it to:

1. Initialize a git repo
2. Create a GitHub repo
3. Add, commit, and push the master branch
4. Create, checkout, and push a dev and new-feature branch

Actual: `bash: syntax error near &&`

Comment: you'll want to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) You can mark your own answer as accepted if it was the best one for your situation.

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks for the link. SO requires that I wait two days before accepting my answer. Your answer's very helpful so I upvoted it, and the comments on my answer/my answer are technically the answer, so I'm marking that as the solution when I can.

Answer (score 2):

bash doesn't know that the command continues on to the next line unless:

- you use a line continuation

  ```
  createRepo () {
    git init \
    && hub create \
    && echo "/node_modules" >.gitignore \
    && ...
  ```
- you put the `&&` at the end of the line

  ```
  createRepo () {
    git init &&
    hub create &&
    echo "/node_modules" >.gitignore &&
    ...
  ```

Comment: After re-sourcing the `.bashrc`, I confirmed your syntax works where mine didn't. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Bash loads the `~/.bashrc` file once at the start, so I had to restart Bash entirely.

My `repo` alias worked after that.

Comment: You can also run source ~/.bashrc and you won’t have to restart

Comment: `.` is an alias for `source`, so you can also run `. ~/.bashrc`